# google maps v3 marker using loop

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am Using Google maps api v3 and want to make markers using loop in JS on also display the data on infowindow from Db.I want to make markers on map as i add row into DB.
The work have i done fot this is bellow but i unable to Compelete my target.

```
<%  Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "GPS")
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim GPS As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE")
        Next

        %>
```

And JS code in map function to make marker

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


var GPS='<%=GPS %>'

var Infowindow=GPS

var image = 'ico/Ch.png';
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(GPS);
var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: LatLng,
    map: map,
    icon:image,
    title:""

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(Infowindow);
  infowindow.open(map,marker0);

});
```

Through this code i am unalbe to make even one marker.I want to create marker on map as i add GPS in DB Column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google.maps.LatLng requires *two* arguments.  You are using one: *GPS*.  Since you don't say what the value of *GPS* looks like, this should get you started.

replace:

```
var GPS='<%=GPS %>'
```

with:

```
var GPS = '<%=GPS %>'.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
```

replace:

```
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(GPS);
```

with:

```
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(GPS[0], GPS[1]);
```

Comment: I am Getting Compilation Error of "GPS is Not declared" and how can i make all markers in with loop in JS from Server Side loop that ?